# Why does my function think that "uiouioiu"is a plaindrome?

Tags: python, palindrome

I was reading Introduction to Computation and Programming using Python and there in an exercise, we had to write a function which would tell us if a given word is a palindrome or not, **recursively**.

This is the code which I wrote:

```
word = input()

def isPalindrome(x):
    if len(x) > 1:
        if x[0] == x[-1] and isPalindrome(x[1:-1]):
            return('The word is Plaindrome.')
        else:
            return('It is not.')
    else:
        return(True) #As this is a base case.


print(isPalindrome(word))
```

This seems to work for all the words I pass into it except **uiouioiu**.
`isPalindrome(uiouioiu)` returns `The word is Palindrome`.

Could someone explain what is happening?

**EDIT 1**: If I modify the code to:

```
word = input()

def isPalindrome(x):
    if len(x) > 1:
        if x[0] == x[-1] and isPalindrome(x[1:-1]):
            return(True)
        else:
            return(False)
    else:
        return(True) #As this is a base case.


print(isPalindrome(word))
```

`isPalindrome(uiouioiu)` returns `False` as expected. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is that "It is not" is converted into True, so when you analyze 
"uiouioiu" the process eventually has to check the middle part "ui", the problem is that the answer "It is not" is then interpreted as True.

The same behaviour should also be obtained when testing the word "abca"

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. Could you please explain what do you mean by " `It is not`is converted into True" ? `It is not == True` evaluates to `False`!

Comment: Check instead something like if('It is not'): do something

Comment: Put the argument 'It is not' inside an if statement and check if it does what it is supposed to do.

Comment: For example  if 'it is not':
    print("hola\n");

Comment: The idea is that non empty strings turn into True when you put them inside an if

Comment: I don't know, I don't use python, but that is the way it works with c++ also. It probably has to do with the fact that == first checks if the two variables have the same type or something? Or maybe == checks if the two things are exactly the same. I don't know to be honest, but i do know that if you use a non empty string in an if statement it will interpret it as True.

Comment: Glad to help !!

Comment: @RahulJ The concept you are looking for is called "truthiness" or "truthyness" and it is not limited to Python. See [this blog post](https://blog.jrheard.com/truthiness-and-short-circuit-evaluation-in-python) for an explanation. Be aware that similar (but different) rules exist in other languages, and it's the job of the programmer to know these rules.

Comment: I don't think it's the job of the programmer to be honest. I'm sick of "programmers" being held to such high standards.

Comment: Please do not answer off-topic questions.